# UPDATE INNER JOIN SQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm building a notification system where, the user is shown the number of new posts of people he follows. In this case I'm user `7`

I have two tables

Community

```
  id_follower   id_followed
      7               3
      7               5
      7               7
```

Posts

```
  id_post    id_user_post  post     status
     1              3       hi        0
     2              5       hello     0
     3              9       how are   0
```

What I want is to update the  post `status` to `1` of every user I follow and have posted something

This just update everything

```
    update posts as p
     inner join community as c on
           c.id_follower = 7
                       set p.status=1
```

In this case it should return 2 rows posts table updated (2,3)

Comment: which database you are using  ???

Comment: Just MySql & php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the condition for id_follower related  to id_follower

```
 update posts as p
 inner join community as c on  c.id_follower = 7 
    and p._id_user_post = c.id_followed
  set p.status=1
```

Comment: I did it. Thank you ;)

Comment: hey I have this new question, I would be glad if you can check it, thank you. stackoverflow.com/q/48999783/9369685